# Runtime of classic Cracking the Coding Interview question a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3?

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, hashmap, runtime, big-o

Hi I am going over Gayle Laakmann's CTIC book and I came across her question

```
print all possible integer solutions for a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3 where a,b,c,d can be integers 1 - 1000
```

She gave some pseudo code which looks like this:

First solution

```
n = 1000
for c from 1 to n
   for d from 1 to n
      result = c^3 + d^3
      append(c,d) to list at value map[result]

for a from 1 to n
   for b from 1 to n
      result = a^3 + b^3
      list = map.get(result)
      for each pair in list
         print a, b, pair
```

Second Solution

```
n = 1000
for c from 1 to n
   for d from 1 to n
      result = c^3 + d^3
      append (c,d) to list at value map[result]

for each result, list in map
   for each pair1 in list
      for each pair2 in list
         print pair1, pair2
```

How do any of these solutions get an O(n^2) running time? Even in the first solution the second set of for loops you also iterate over the pairs in your map so wouldn't that be O(n^3)?

Comment: How did you figure out the mathematics for that?

Comment: Yeah, never mind :P Made a critical mistake there...

Comment: I think it depends on the asymptotics of [this OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A173677). I did a quick search but didn't find anything useful; there might not be a known tight bound on the asymptotic growth rate. That said, the max up to 10,000 is 4 ways (and that's including 0 as a cube), so at least for the range up to 1,000 the running time should be roughly quadratic.

Comment: That said, the max up to 10,000 is 4 ways (and that's including 0 as a cube), so at least for the range up to 1,000 the running time should be roughly quadratic.

Comment: The solution by Manoj is incorrect as it excludes all those integers that can be written as the sum of two positive cubes in 3 different ways. (Such numbers do exist when n = 1000). Reasoning about any algorithm to solve this problem requires reasoning about the number of ways sums of two cubes can be written as sums of two other cubes.

Comment: @box_of_donuts thanks for the correction, i removed my answer.

Comment: Check if this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44859599/solving-a3-b4-c3-d3-best-runtime

Answer (score 1):

If `r(m)` is the number of ordered representations of `m` as the sum of two positive integer cubes, then it is known that `sum(r(m)^2, m=0..M)` is `Theta(M^(2/3))`, see <sup>[1]</sup>.

This implies that the number of solutions your algorithm will print is `O(n^2)`, because the largest possible sum of two cubes you will generate is `2*N^3` and the maximum number of solutions for a given `m` is `r(m)^2` to account for all combinations of the representations on both sides of the equation.

Because the innermost loop always iterates exactly ones per printed result, it is then also only executed at most `O(n^2)` times, making the whole algorithm `Theta(n^2)` (due to the outer loops iteration time).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Hooley (1963): *On the representations of a number as the sum of two cubes*; https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01111429