# finding all results of a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3, problem caused by Math.pow() method

Tags: java, math, pow

**Problem** : print all +ve integer solution of the equation 
         `a^3 + b^3 = c^3 + d^3` 
where `a, b, c, d` are integers bw `1 to 1000`
Facing issue with `Math.pow()` function.

So I have written two code one is brute force and another one with a little optimisation. 
The first one is showing correct output while the 2nd one is not and this is due to the power function.

`Math.pow(0,1/3)` = `1`   while it should be `0`

```
class Find_a3_b3__c3_d3{
    // final static int n = 100;

    // solution 1  : BRUTE FORCE
    public static void bruteForce(){        // O(N^4)
        int n = 5;

        int resultCount = 0;
        for(int a=0; a<n ; a++){
            for(int b=0; b<n; b++){
                for(int c=0; c<n; c++){
                    for(int d=0; d<n; d++){
                        int a_3 = a*a*a;
                        int b_3 = b*b*b;
                        int c_3 = c*c*c;
                        int d_3 = d*d*d;
                        if(a_3 + b_3 == c_3 + d_3){
                            System.out.println((resultCount++) + "   a: "+a +"  b: "+b + "   ---    c: "+c + "  d: "+d );
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }



    // solution 2  : BRUTE FORCE
    // idea is : as we know d is going to have one value for each pair of a,b & c so
    //           if we know a b & c , then we can find d by the relation  cubeRoot (a_3 + b_3 - c_3);
    public static void littleBetter(){        // O(N^4)
        int n = 5;

        int resultCount = 0;
        for(int a=0; a<n ; a++){
            for(int b=0; b<n; b++){
                for(int c=0; c<n; c++){
                    int a_3 = a*a*a;
                    int b_3 = b*b*b;
                    int c_3 = c*c*c;
                    System.out.println(a +" " + b+" " + c +" ");
                    System.out.println(a_3 +" " + b_3+" " + c_3 +" " + Math.pow(a_3 + b_3 - c_3, 1/3));
                    int d = (int) Math.pow(a_3 + b_3 - c_3, 1/3);
                    int d_3 = d*d*d;

                    if(a_3 + b_3 == c_3 + d_3){
                        System.out.println((resultCount++) + "   a: "+a +"  b: "+b + "   ---    c: "+c + "  d: "+d );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bruteForce();//          O(n^4)
        littleBetter(); //       O(n^3)

        System.out.println( Math.pow(0,1/3));
        System.out.println( Math.pow(0,1));
        System.out.println( Math.pow(0,0));
        System.out.println( Math.pow(34,0));
        System.out.println( Math.pow(34,-0));
        System.out.println( Math.pow(0,1));
    }
}
```

If you execute the program, you will see that the no of row of result are different too.

**Output**

```
     ~/Documents/CTCI Codes >> javac Find_a3_b3__c3_d3.java                                                                                                   
     ~/Documents/CTCI Codes >> java Find_a3_b3__c3_d3                                                                                                         
    0   a: 0  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 0
    1   a: 0  b: 1   ---    c: 0  d: 1
    2   a: 0  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 0
    3   a: 0  b: 2   ---    c: 0  d: 2
    4   a: 0  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 0
    5   a: 0  b: 3   ---    c: 0  d: 3
    6   a: 0  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 0
    7   a: 0  b: 4   ---    c: 0  d: 4
    8   a: 0  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 0
    9   a: 1  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 1
    10   a: 1  b: 0   ---    c: 1  d: 0
    11   a: 1  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 1
    12   a: 1  b: 2   ---    c: 1  d: 2
    13   a: 1  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 1
    14   a: 1  b: 3   ---    c: 1  d: 3
    15   a: 1  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 1
    16   a: 1  b: 4   ---    c: 1  d: 4
    17   a: 1  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 1
    18   a: 2  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 2
    19   a: 2  b: 0   ---    c: 2  d: 0
    20   a: 2  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 2
    21   a: 2  b: 1   ---    c: 2  d: 1
    22   a: 2  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 2
    23   a: 2  b: 3   ---    c: 2  d: 3
    24   a: 2  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 2
    25   a: 2  b: 4   ---    c: 2  d: 4
    26   a: 2  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 2
    27   a: 3  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 3
    28   a: 3  b: 0   ---    c: 3  d: 0
    29   a: 3  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 3
    30   a: 3  b: 1   ---    c: 3  d: 1
    31   a: 3  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 3
    32   a: 3  b: 2   ---    c: 3  d: 2
    33   a: 3  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 3
    34   a: 3  b: 4   ---    c: 3  d: 4
    35   a: 3  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 3
    36   a: 4  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 4
    37   a: 4  b: 0   ---    c: 4  d: 0
    38   a: 4  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 4
    39   a: 4  b: 1   ---    c: 4  d: 1
    40   a: 4  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 4
    41   a: 4  b: 2   ---    c: 4  d: 2
    42   a: 4  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 4
    43   a: 4  b: 3   ---    c: 4  d: 3
    44   a: 4  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 4



    0 0 0 
    0 0 0 1.0
    0 0 1 
    0 0 1 1.0
    0 0 2 
    0 0 8 1.0
    0 0 3 
    0 0 27 1.0
    0 0 4 
    0 0 64 1.0
    0 1 0 
    0 1 0 1.0
    0   a: 0  b: 1   ---    c: 0  d: 1
    0 1 1 
    0 1 1 1.0
    0 1 2 
    0 1 8 1.0
    0 1 3 
    0 1 27 1.0
    0 1 4 
    0 1 64 1.0
    0 2 0 
    0 8 0 1.0
    0 2 1 
    0 8 1 1.0
    0 2 2 
    0 8 8 1.0
    0 2 3 
    0 8 27 1.0
    0 2 4 
    0 8 64 1.0
    0 3 0 
    0 27 0 1.0
    0 3 1 
    0 27 1 1.0
    0 3 2 
    0 27 8 1.0
    0 3 3 
    0 27 27 1.0
    0 3 4 
    0 27 64 1.0
    0 4 0 
    0 64 0 1.0
    0 4 1 
    0 64 1 1.0
    0 4 2 
    0 64 8 1.0
    0 4 3 
    0 64 27 1.0
    0 4 4 
    0 64 64 1.0
    1 0 0 
    1 0 0 1.0
    1   a: 1  b: 0   ---    c: 0  d: 1
    1 0 1 
    1 0 1 1.0
    1 0 2 
    1 0 8 1.0
    1 0 3 
    1 0 27 1.0
    1 0 4 
    1 0 64 1.0
    1 1 0 
    1 1 0 1.0
    1 1 1 
    1 1 1 1.0
    2   a: 1  b: 1   ---    c: 1  d: 1
    1 1 2 
    1 1 8 1.0
    1 1 3 
    1 1 27 1.0
    1 1 4 
    1 1 64 1.0
    1 2 0 
    1 8 0 1.0
    1 2 1 
    1 8 1 1.0
    1 2 2 
    1 8 8 1.0
    3   a: 1  b: 2   ---    c: 2  d: 1
    1 2 3 
    1 8 27 1.0
    1 2 4 
    1 8 64 1.0
    1 3 0 
    1 27 0 1.0
    1 3 1 
    1 27 1 1.0
    1 3 2 
    1 27 8 1.0
    1 3 3 
    1 27 27 1.0
    4   a: 1  b: 3   ---    c: 3  d: 1
    1 3 4 
    1 27 64 1.0
    1 4 0 
    1 64 0 1.0
    1 4 1 
    1 64 1 1.0
    1 4 2 
    1 64 8 1.0
    1 4 3 
    1 64 27 1.0
    1 4 4 
    1 64 64 1.0
    5   a: 1  b: 4   ---    c: 4  d: 1
    2 0 0 
    8 0 0 1.0
    2 0 1 
    8 0 1 1.0
    2 0 2 
    8 0 8 1.0
    2 0 3 
    8 0 27 1.0
    2 0 4 
    8 0 64 1.0
    2 1 0 
    8 1 0 1.0
    2 1 1 
    8 1 1 1.0
    2 1 2 
    8 1 8 1.0
    6   a: 2  b: 1   ---    c: 2  d: 1
    2 1 3 
    8 1 27 1.0
    2 1 4 
    8 1 64 1.0
    2 2 0 
    8 8 0 1.0
    2 2 1 
    8 8 1 1.0
    2 2 2 
    8 8 8 1.0
    2 2 3 
    8 8 27 1.0
    2 2 4 
    8 8 64 1.0
    2 3 0 
    8 27 0 1.0
    2 3 1 
    8 27 1 1.0
    2 3 2 
    8 27 8 1.0
    2 3 3 
    8 27 27 1.0
    2 3 4 
    8 27 64 1.0
    2 4 0 
    8 64 0 1.0
    2 4 1 
    8 64 1 1.0
    2 4 2 
    8 64 8 1.0
    2 4 3 
    8 64 27 1.0
    2 4 4 
    8 64 64 1.0
    3 0 0 
    27 0 0 1.0
    3 0 1 
    27 0 1 1.0
    3 0 2 
    27 0 8 1.0
    3 0 3 
    27 0 27 1.0
    3 0 4 
    27 0 64 1.0
    3 1 0 
    27 1 0 1.0
    3 1 1 
    27 1 1 1.0
    3 1 2 
    27 1 8 1.0
    3 1 3 
    27 1 27 1.0
    7   a: 3  b: 1   ---    c: 3  d: 1
    3 1 4 
    27 1 64 1.0
    3 2 0 
    27 8 0 1.0
    3 2 1 
    27 8 1 1.0
    3 2 2 
    27 8 8 1.0
    3 2 3 
    27 8 27 1.0
    3 2 4 
    27 8 64 1.0
    3 3 0 
    27 27 0 1.0
    3 3 1 
    27 27 1 1.0
    3 3 2 
    27 27 8 1.0
    3 3 3 
    27 27 27 1.0
    3 3 4 
    27 27 64 1.0
    3 4 0 
    27 64 0 1.0
    3 4 1 
    27 64 1 1.0
    3 4 2 
    27 64 8 1.0
    3 4 3 
    27 64 27 1.0
    3 4 4 
    27 64 64 1.0
    4 0 0 
    64 0 0 1.0
    4 0 1 
    64 0 1 1.0
    4 0 2 
    64 0 8 1.0
    4 0 3 
    64 0 27 1.0
    4 0 4 
    64 0 64 1.0
    4 1 0 
    64 1 0 1.0
    4 1 1 
    64 1 1 1.0
    4 1 2 
    64 1 8 1.0
    4 1 3 
    64 1 27 1.0
    4 1 4 
    64 1 64 1.0
    8   a: 4  b: 1   ---    c: 4  d: 1
    4 2 0 
    64 8 0 1.0
    4 2 1 
    64 8 1 1.0
    4 2 2 
    64 8 8 1.0
    4 2 3 
    64 8 27 1.0
    4 2 4 
    64 8 64 1.0
    4 3 0 
    64 27 0 1.0
    4 3 1 
    64 27 1 1.0
    4 3 2 
    64 27 8 1.0
    4 3 3 
    64 27 27 1.0
    4 3 4 
    64 27 64 1.0
    4 4 0 
    64 64 0 1.0
    4 4 1 
    64 64 1 1.0
    4 4 2 
    64 64 8 1.0
    4 4 3 
    64 64 27 1.0
    4 4 4 
    64 64 64 1.0



    1.0
    0.0
    1.0
    1.0
    1.0
    0.0
     ~/Documents/CTCI Codes >>
```

Comment: 1/3 = 0 (by default 1/3 is seen as integer division). Try (double) 1 / 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you divide two integers the answer becomes an integer too, that's because you get 1 instead of zero. `1/3` is equal to zero and `Math.pow(0,0)` is equal to 1. instead you can use `Math.pow(0,1./3))` to get 0.
**UPDATE**
 You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454133/write-all-solutions-for-a3-b3-c3-d3) to see better solution that are already provided.

Comment: This problem is because of 1 is not dividable by 3. When you divide 1 by 3 you get 0.3333...33. So this way `Math.pow(64, 0.3)` equals `3.4822022531844965` and `Math.pow(64, 0.33)` equals `3.9449308179734368` and so on. This problem can be solved simply by using `Math.round()`. Refer to link below to know more about floating point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322749/retain-precision-with-double-in-java

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in a comment the problem you encounter is probably due to 1/3 being evaluated as 0. Casting 1 or 3 to a floating point number should solve that.

How ever, I would suggest further optimization: calculate x^3 for x = 1 to n and store results in both an array and a hash set. Then for every combination of 3 numbers in the array test if a+b-c is in the hash set (due to symmetry of a+b you can also spare some duplicates by iterating slightly better on b).

Edit: granted, my optimization sacrifices space complexity.

Comment: Can you paste the code on stackoverflow? I prefer not to open links.

Comment: In my opinion this is the better answer.